# lucene query search

Tags: search, lucene

I have been tasked to use lucene to search in our product table. I have created an index and am searching using a QueryParser with multiple fields, but the results are not what I require.
 I have a product that is stored as LM10, but I want to be able to find it if the search term is LM 10, but it also must be able to match if the search term is Fred LM10 or Fred LM 10.
Any ideas how I can do this in Lucene.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a Tokenizer that splits tokens on word/number changes, apply it both at index and query time. You might use [solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters/#TokenizerFactories) and avoid having to write a custom one.

Comment: Sorry but I am a .net and not a java developer. I cannot believe I am the only .net developer who requires this from Lucene.net and it is not built into the core.